# how to change my email format perl email

Tags: perl, email

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$SUBJ="Your unique confirmation link";
$MSG="message.txt";
$USERS="list.txt";

open(IN,$USERS);

$id=12345;
while(chop($line=<IN>)){
    open(SM,"|/usr/sbin/sendmail $line");
    print(SM "To: $line\n");
    print(SM "Subject: $SUBJ\n");
    print(SM "Message-ID: <".time().".$id.qmail\@mycompany.com>\n");
    print(SM "From: \"mycompany\" <noreply@message.mycompany.com>\n");
    print("Message sent to $line\n");
    print(SM "Content-Type: text/html\n"); 
    open(FILE,$MSG);
    while($line=<FILE>){
    print(SM $line);
    }
    close(FILE);
    close(SM);
    $id++;
}

close(IN);
```

I have this perl emailer script. This script is sending to all emails in list.txt an email message which is in message.txt. In message.txt it's a html code. This script is working perfect bt
My problem is that i want to send a message like this:
 Hello blah blah your unique link is: http://www.mycompany.com/mylink.php?id=34. I want a random link.In mean in each email sent to have another mylink.php?id=randmom. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: any reason why you use perl here and php else where?

Comment: Yes, I need random and unique. ANy help?maybe A posibility can be to integrate the message directly into script. But how can I do this?

Comment: The core of your question is "How can I generate a random unique ID number?" This has nothing to do with email, so you should edit out the extraneous parts of your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I dont think this is enough . I want also to integrate in the message.

Comment: You said your script that sends HTML messages "is working perfectly," so it seems you already know how to 1) send email with Perl and 2) include HTML in emails. It seems like the only missing piece is generating the unique IDs, no?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to solve two problems:

- How to generate a unique ID per email sent
- How to embed a unique link in each email (currently generated from a fixed text file)

For the first point, it really depends what the ID is being used for. One possibility is to just have a persistent counter, stored in a database or file, that increments for each email issued. Another possibility is to generate a UUID - you can use one of the many [UUID modules on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~lzap/UUID-0.05/UUID.pm) for this. Either way if the ID is to have meaning to your PHP scripts then you would want to be storing it somewhere.

For the second point, there are a number of possible solutions. The simplest is to stop using a separate file as an email template and put the template inline in your script, like this:

```
print(<<_EOT_);
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hello, here is your <a href="http://www.mycompany.com/mylink.php?id=${UniqueID}">Link</a>
   ... etc ...
  </body>
</html>
_EOT_
```

The above example uses a 'here doc' to allow you to embed your email text directly in your script. Everything up to the `_EOT_` is part of the string that is printed. Make sure that `_EOT_` is on the line by itself and with no trailing spaces!

A more maintainable solution, which would allow you to continue to use a separate template file, would be to use the excellent [Template::Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Template-Toolkit-2.25/).